# Can't see my item on ListView

Tags: android, listview

Java Code:

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {


    public BlankFragment() {}


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
        ListView listView=(ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview);
        ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();
        listItems.add("example");
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listItems);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return view;
    }

}
```

XML code:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="layout.BlankFragment">


        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="204dp"
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:background="#d36868"
            android:layout_gravity="center"></ListView>

    </FrameLayout>
```

This is my code ... I have initialize a ListView and i tried to add an item called "example" . When i run this app I can see my listview but without any ietm.

Comment: Try to use custom adapter

Comment: **I can see my listview but without any ietm????.** can not get you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with the code above.Because I tried.
[image]

I think it's some error code that you didn't get the code out of it.Such as Other Fragment,Activity,and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `wrap_content` instead of fixed height

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="layout.BlankFragment">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:background="#d36868"
            android:layout_gravity="center"></ListView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: At the time of setting adapter no need to call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();